# How to access next link with PHP when you parsing data

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping, web-crawler

My idea basically is like this:

Enter an `$url` this url has like 20 items and at the bottom there's page 1,2,3,4....10 and `>` for next, what i want is that he access this page sees if there's `>` by the css selector `id` or `class` till there's none and after that stops, how can i do this?

this is used for parsing data, and i want to do it all at once like this is the main `$url` so parse the data then, check if it's the last page if not, the `$url' become the next page`$url`.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Have you looked at the DOM class? What's the url in question?

Comment: yes, the parsing function is done but my issue is with making this url thing a bit auto so i dont replace the URL my self for each page like page 2, page 3 ... etc

Comment: If you have control of the url generation this can be done with preg_match().  If you post the actual data then someone will doubtless enjoy writing the regex for you.

Comment: Your idea is clear, but what is your programming question?

Comment: @hakre second paragraph, last few words.

Comment: @bwoebi: Enter an `$url` where-in? A simple "how can I do this" is hardly a question. All we can say is that OP can not do this otherwise he would not have asked. Therefore the question answers itself and therefore the programming part is missing.

Comment: @hakre don't know, his idea is not clear to me; I just see a question xD

Comment: @bwoebi: Alright, I see. Easy peasy, I answered it.

Comment: BTW still don't get why this is closed, it's a real question, and i'm trying to make a process automatic than a manual copy paste. DON'T UNDERSTAND YOU MODERATORS !!!

Answer (score 2):

> ... how can i do this?

I'd say right now you can't do it. You're missing to program it I assume from what you ask for therefore the answer is that you can do it by programming it.

One problem albeit remains. PHP has no CSS selectors. Those are in the DOM of the Browser but not in PHP's DOM. Therefore you need to find a solution to not use CSS selectors but instead query the document differently, for example with [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) which is supported in version 1.0 by PHP's DOM.

Comment: The main idea is the selector, and i can select it with `find` but my issue is the acction after that, like ok i found it how can i make it access the link that is the son of that parent, and keep doing it till i don't have that parent anymore to select, do you understand?